# Send message to several groups using Django Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm building a chat app. I'd like to know:
1) If the way I'm currently implementing chat is incorrect / bad coding practice
2) How to send the message to several groups

The base idea is the following:

- Each user connects to a specific channel (.../ws/), and is part of a specific group
- One group contains one user, and a user can only participate to one group
- When a user sends a message to another user, they also send a list of user IDs to whom the message should be transferred.
- The message is then sent to the different groups

I'd like to send the message to those users in an efficient/scalable way.

Below is the current way I'm implementing chat where the message is sent to one user (only 1 user is specified in data[userID])

```
def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        print('Websocket received info!')
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        # Send the message to the specified user
        self.send_channel_message(data[userID], data['message'])

    def send_channel_message(self, group_name, message):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            '{}'.format(group_name), # Specify intented group
            {
                'type': 'channel_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    def channel_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

One way to do this is by looping through the users to whom the chat message was intented, and send the messages one by one to them.

```
    def receive(self, text_data):
        print('Websocket received info!')
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        # Send the message to the specified user
        for userID in data[userID]
            self.send_channel_message(userID, data['message'])
```

Is this method best coding practice?

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This is almost certainly the only way to do this, you can only (as of writing) send a message to one channel at a time unless you use groups. Do you have separate workers in your deployment?

Comment: Unless you want to create groups dynamically but if these are short term/a one time thing then you would not get any benefit

Comment: @IainShelvington It's one server that's handles everything (user auth, notifications, storing data, chat...etc). The communication between members of a multi-user chat isn't a one time thing and could span 100s, or 1000s of messages. Is it more efficient to create Groups which contain several users, rather than the above implementation where chat messages are transferred to several groups? Would there be additional overhead if messages are transferred to several groups vs one group containing several users?